# MIPS Differences among manipulating array address using add, addu, and addi

Tags: mips

I am a newcomer to MIPS and I am confused with the following 3 operations when it comes to accessing elements in an array. For example, if I want to change the value of an integer array at index 1 to 6 and right now I only get $s0 for the base address of the array, A[], then what should I do? Code example is like this:

```
addi $t0, $zero, 4
add  $s0, $s0, $t0
addi  ($s0), $zero, 6
```

or

```
addi $t0, $zero, 4
addu $s0, $s0, $t0
addi ($s0), $zero, 6
```

or

```
addi $s0, $s0, 4
addi ($s0), $zero, 6
```

Could you explain the reason and point out special cases as well.

Comment: None of those are valid. To manipulate values in memory you need to load the value into a register first (e.g. using `lw`), then manipulate the value, and then write it back (e.g. using `sw`).

Comment: @Michael Then what about the way that I used to access certain position in an array? Is it valid?